# Is is possible to make a text generator with sklearn?

Tags: scikit-learn, rnn, text-generation

So recently I made a Tensorflow model using RNN (Recurrent neural networks) and I was wondering if it was possible with sklearn too, through the usage of SVMs or Naive bayes.

I searched up many articles on google but didn't find a feasible solution to it. So is it even possible to build a text generator with sklearn?

If so, whats the base code to make that model?

Comment: You can use n-grams, using: from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer. See this page: https://predictivehacks.com/text-generation-for-instagram-using-n-grams/

Comment: SVM or NB are supervised learning methods, normally text generation is unsupervised. You can look into [language models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_model)

Comment: no it is not that's what i think btw i have never used sklearn